# Splitting string on the first occurance of any one of multiple delimiters

Tags: python, split

Lets say i have a string

`a = "Apple;Bananas-Mangoes/Strawberries"`

Now what i want to do is split the string on the first occurance of either of these characters(; or - or /).

like
`b = ["Apple","Bananas-Mangoes/Strawberries"]`

But if used a different character at the start instead of the ; , i want to split from that instead.

`a = "Apple/Bananas-Mangoes;Strawberries"`

`b = ["Apple","Bananas-Mangoes;Strawberries"]`

So any way to achieve this in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `re.split`:

```
import re
a = "Apple;Bananas-Mangoes/Strawberries"
result = re.split('[;/\-]', a, 1)
```

Output:

```
['Apple', 'Bananas-Mangoes/Strawberries']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `any()` which returns True if the condition is met:

```
a = "Apple/Bananas-Mangoes;Strawberries"
not_l=['-','/',';']
for i in a:
    if any(i==k for k in not_l):
        c=a.split(i)
        print(c)
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following

```
import re

s1='Apple;Bananas-Mangoes/Strawberries'
s2='Apple/Bananas-Mangoes;Strawberries'

p ='(;|\\/|-)'

s=s1
m=re.search(p,s)
print([s[0:m.regs[0][0]],s[m.regs[0][0]+1:-1]])

s=s2
m=re.search(p,s)
print([s[0:m.regs[0][0]],s[m.regs[0][0]+1:-1]])
```